# Incorrect selection of kernel headers: expected 4.9.x, got 4.6.x with BR 2022.02 and bootlin toolchain from menuconfig

Tags: buildroot, toolchain

I wanted to try out the bootlin toolchain support in buildroot, because now I can simply select them in menuconfig.

- BR version: branch 2022.02
- Defconfig: atmel_sama5d3_xplained_defconfig
- Toolchain: `Toolchain -> Toolchain (Bootlin toolchains)"

  - "Bootlin toolchain variant": armv7-eabihf glibc stable 2021.11-1

On a clean git checkout, after loading and modifying the above defconfig via menuconfig, the build stops with:

```
Incorrect selection of kernel headers: expected 4.9.x, got 4.6.x
```

The expectation (autogenerated by helper script gen-bootlin-toolchains) seems to be ok, because the [release announcement](https://bootlin.com/blog/bootlin-toolchains-updated-2021-11-release/) also mentions 4.9 for stable toolchain versions.

Any idea what goes wrong here? Or how buildroot calculates the "got" version? (I don't see any downloaded files in `output/build/toolchain-external-bootlin-2021.11-1` other then the stamp files and the file-list files)

If I download the file manually and check `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/linux/version.h`, the version is indeed 4.9

---

I could just manually download the toolchain and specify the parameters manually, but then the bootlin integration (which is nice) doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this mis-match was that the bootlin toolchain won't be downloaded by buildroot automatically, but is expected in the PATH as `arm-linux-gcc`. I did have `arm-linux-gcc` in my PATH but linked to another toolchain.

After manually installing (download+extract) the bootlin toolchain and adding the "bin" folder of the toolchain to the PATH of the environment in which buildroot was run, the build succeeded as expected.

Comment: This wouldn't have been an issue, if the "Toolchain origin" is set to Download and Extract.